# The use of the word "garbage"

Tags: discussion, etiquette

So I answered a question and received [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652250/how-do-i-read-a-file-and-import-the-contents-into-a-list-using-python/32652297?noredirect=1#comment53151181_32652297). Yes, not a full answer to a bad question.

Yet, I get told my answer is "garbage" as the question. Not nice. Instead of working I tried to help somebody learning python, and I get called names.

Some decency will be nice.  Maybe the question should be closed because is a duplicate, maybe what I wrote is incomplete. But it is still wrong to get called garbage.

Comment: That doesn't look to me like he called your answer garbage. I read that as "this is not an answer. Also, the question is bad."

Comment: To be fair to the commentor, he didn't say your answer was garbage. Just that the question was. But that was still wrong. He was simply saying that your answer doesn't answer the poor question. Which it appears that it doesn't. And, yes, people should be nicer. Anyway, you could flag the comment if you are so inclined. But, since *you know and have stated* the answer is wrong, it would be best just to delete it, imo

Comment: Why exactly is there so much drama about this right now? I down voted the answer, a little popup shows up "Comment to show what's wrong with this answer". Obviously I do that. Apologising firstly, I write "Sorry, this just isn't an answer". And, thinking that the guy who wrote the answer could feel bad, I add: "The question is garbage too", saying that it probably isn't cauchy's fault

Comment: @wap26 you can't infer that. He only explicitly said that the question was garbage and that the answer wasn't an answer. Maybe he thinks it's a fine answer given a different question. Anyway, still not much to be done but flag the already busy mods if it so offensive to someone, delete the post, or move on

Comment: @akalikin because we like drama on meta? It gives me something to do before diving into this horrible code on my other monitor

Comment: @codeMagic No objection then :)

Comment: @codeMagic, same as me ; especially on Friday afternoon...

Comment: Yay, justice, both of our first comments are now deleted :)

Comment: Any of the other comments referring to the 'name calling' should probably be removed too, as they're now obsolete.

Comment: The problem is that the use of "too" here is ambiguous. akalikin meant 'too' as in, "this is an additional problem" but the OP read it as "this is *also* garbage" which implies that two things are being called garbage, not just one. Since the first sentence does say the answer is bad I can see how that happened.

Comment: Entire question has since been removed.

Answer (score 24):

The right thing to do here is flag the comment as "rude or offensive" (if you believe it is; personally I do not). That is all.

Also, don't rise to it and call this person names/be offensive yourself (you commented: "Get a life!") - you're just perpetuating the problem.

There is already a [be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy in place.

Comment: Can I get a "reverse polarity" badge for the q having -11 and my answer having +11. No? ok :(

Comment: isn't there Reversal badge? For +20 on an answer. Just +9 more votes :)

Comment: woohoo achieverment unlocked!

Comment: haha well done :)